# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80210064 ERROR (WIA Scanner)

Tags: .net, wpf, dll, hardware, wia

I have WPF Application using scanner to scan document I used WIA dll for scanning , but when I treid to scan it's showing me "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80210064"

```
  ImageFile scanResult = (ImageFile)commonDialogClass.ShowTransfer(_scannnerItem, FormatID.wiaFormatPNG, true);
```

system crash when i try to return ImageFile from ShowTransfer() Method

Note:
Scanner working fine when I tried to scan document from outside of my application